# iOS UITableViewCell layout update

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using custom button (extended UIButton) in UITableViewCell. This button has method updateLayout, which add some graphical adjustments (borders, image, edge insets, ...).

I'm calling this updateLayout method in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ProfileSelect *cityButton = (ProfileSelect *)[cell viewWithTag:4];

    [cityButton updateLayout];
}
```

When I dynamically add new cell to the table, the button is not displayed correctly (some properties are OK, some are not).

When I add another new cell, the previous button updates its layout and is displayed correctly. However the new one has the same problem.

Where should I call custom updateLayout method to display buttons correctly?

Comment: Did you try to put `[cityButton updateLayout];` in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` after created a cell?

Comment: Yes I did, however it did not work as expected + it cause constraints issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding category to UIButton+RuntimeAttribute.

I used Xcode **User Defined Runtime attributes** to define required parameters:

[image]

And override setter methods in category to update layout:

```
- (void)setBorderBottom:(BOOL)borderBottom
{
    UIView *border = [UIView new];
    border.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"808080"];
    [border setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, self.frame.size.width, borderWidth);
    [self addSubview:border];
}

- (void)setBorderLeftFaded:(BOOL)borderLeftFaded
{
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_field_left_border"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)setContentPadding:(float)contentPadding
{
    [self setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, contentPadding, 0.0, contentPadding)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced by using tags here, I think tags might have to be unique per viewController, not per view therefore you would be overriding your view tags which could lead to your unexpected behavior.

I suggest you subclass UITableViewCell and give it a cityButton property.
Then your code should work like thie

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    YourCustomCell *customCell = (YourCustomCell *)cell;
    [cell.cityButton updateLayout];
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I switch the logic to UITableViewCell subclass, however the behaviour of the custom button remains the same.

Comment: OK, i suggest you move your code to cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I did that, however it did not work as expected + it cause constraints issues.

Answer (score 1):

If your button's borders, insets are all the same, it's a good practice to set them up in your custom cell, override `-(void)awakeFromNib` if it is Nib or `- (void)layoutSubviews` if programmatically.

If they are different decided by your data, then you can set them in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, since cell is reused, so do not get mixed about the datasource.

Comment: They're all the same. I subclassed the UITableViewCell and moved the updateLayout to the -(void)layoutSubviews method (in the subclass) but the behaviour remains the same.

Comment: @Fliper333 There can be plenty of reasons, is your button nil when you set them? Or did you add your button to your cell's content view? It's better to post your code

Comment: The button is in cell prototype (added to cell's content view via Xcode interface builder) and has a tag.